# How to get the last order of a customer in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

I am using *"[How can I get the latest order id in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46688978/how-can-i-get-the-latest-order-id-in-woocommerce)"* answer code that returns last order with a custom function `get_last_order_id()`.

Here is my code attempt where I get order items:

```
<?php

    $latest_order_id = get_last_order_id(); // Last order ID
    $order = wc_get_order( $latest_order_id ); // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
    $order_details = $order->get_data(); // Get the order data in an array
    $order_status = esc_html( wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ) );
    $order_items = $order_details['line_items'];
?>
```

Then I use this in this code:

```
<div class="row last-order">
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <ul>
        <?php
        foreach ($order_items as $product_name) { ?>
          <li><?php echo $product_name['name']; ?></li>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 order-status-box">
      <h6 class="status"><?php echo $order_status; ?></h6>
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-down icon"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to get the last order **for the current customer**. How can I change the custom function `get_last_order_id()` to get the last order **for the current customer**?

I would like to receive the contents of my cart in addition to the latest order from the current user.

Comment: Include a condition for post_author in the WHERE clause then …?

Comment: thank now it's better @LoicTheAztec

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> **Updated**: replaced `WC()->customer` by `new WC_Customer( get_current_user_id() );` for better compatibility.

The Class `WC_Customer` Class include the [`get_last_order()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Customer.html#_get_last_order) method to get the last order for a customer *(so you don't need anymore the custom function `get_last_order_id()` from [this answer thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46688978/how-can-i-get-the-latest-order-id-in-woocommerce))*.

So your code will be:

```
<?php

    // For logged in users only
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) :

    $user_id = get_current_user_id(); // The current user ID

    // Get the WC_Customer instance Object for the current user
    $customer = new WC_Customer( $user_id );

    // Get the last WC_Order Object instance from current customer
    $last_order = $customer->get_last_order();

    $order_id     = $last_order->get_id(); // Get the order id
    $order_data   = $last_order->get_data(); // Get the order unprotected data in an array
    $order_status = $last_order->get_status(); // Get the order status
?>

<div class="row last-order">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <ul>
        <?php foreach ( $last_order->get_items() as $item ) : ?>
            <li><?php echo $item->get_name(); ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 order-status-box">
      <h6 class="status"><?php echo esc_html( wc_get_order_status_name( $order_status ) ); ?></h6>
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-down icon"></i>
    </div>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Tested and works.

**Note:** Now to *"receive the contents of the cart in addition to the latest order from the current user"*, you will have to ask a new question with more details, one question at the time please.

Related:

- [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344?r=SearchResults&s=1|192.6993#44708344)
- [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)
- [How to get Customer details from Order in WooCommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22843504/how-to-get-customer-details-from-order-in-woocommerce/57562904#57562904)

Comment: @PullataPraveen This code still works perfectly on last WooCommerce version. Your comment is completely unclear… What template are you talking about? how are you embedding the code. You should better ask a new question explaining things!

Comment: can you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61753817/how-to-get-latest-order-id-if-user-logged-in-woocommerce

Comment: what if a customer is a guest?

Comment: I used the proposed code and it works perfectly. However, if the user hasn't placed an order, there is a page display error. How to resolve ?