# woocommerce user sql query that does not order in 2 weeks

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am having trouble getting the data of users who did not order in the last 2 weeks in woocommerce.
this code is pulling only one person data, I need a sql query to poll all users

```
function has_bought($user_id) {
    // Get all customer orders
    $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => $user_id,
        'post_type'   => 'shop_order', // WC orders post type
        'post_status' => 'wc-completed' // Only orders with status "completed"
    ) );
    // return "true" when customer has already one order
    return count( $customer_orders ) > 0 ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57603232/how-to-get-the-last-order-of-a-customer-in-woocommerce

Comment: how do i do it for all user?

Comment: To get list of users with criteria -  WP_User_Query - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/

Comment: 10k user what ? mysql down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use date_query. try the below code.

```
function has_bought($user_id) {
    // Get all customer orders
    $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => $user_id,
        'post_type'   => 'shop_order', // WC orders post type
        'post_status' => 'wc-completed', // Only orders with status "completed"
        'date_query' => array(
            'after' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-14 days')) 
        )
    ) );
    // return "true" when customer has already one order
    return count( $customer_orders ) > 0 ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: how do i do it for all user?